# How to run the localization example for ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 rc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to run the localization example for ASP.NET Core which is available here: `https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5Localization/tree/rc2`.

As I understand this is for unofficial version rc2. I have installed:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win             default
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
       1.0.0-rc2-16357   clr     x86          win
```

It seems that 1.0.0-rc2-16357 is not the good one. I would appreciate any instructions on installing the required packages and also running this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repos global.json is using 1.0.0-rc2-16444.

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-16444"
    }
}
```

To install a later package run this:

```
set DNX_UNSTABLE_FEED=https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v2
dnvm upgrade -unstable
dnvm install 1.0.0-rc2-16549 -runtime coreclr -unstable
```

Comment: I tried this but it fails: `There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-coreclr-win-x64 on feed https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2`

Comment: OK I solved it. I use powershell and there I can set the environment variable as `$env:DNX_UNSTABLE_FEED="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v2"`

Comment: Yes. You need to use the `aspnetcidev` feed and to set the variable in PowerShell is different than to set it from the command line.